# Recovering a Lagrangian from CFT data

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory

For conformal field theories (CFTs), one avenue of research has been to 'solve' and classify them based on the CFT data of their operators, constrained by among others, crossing symmetry:

[image]

This has been [extremely fruitful](http://bootstrapcollaboration.com/projects/) but my question is now sort of in reverse to the intents of most research in the field: can we recover a Lagrangian description from CFT data somehow?

I am looking for either an outline of any existing approaches, referrals to the literature or information on obstructions to being able to recover a Lagrangian description.

A point to consider is I am also interested in being able to recover a Lagrangian description of a QFT whose UV CFT possesses the CFT data, but this is a step beyond just finding it for the CFT.

Comment: @QMechanic:  Are you sure this should be community wiki?  I don't think the correct answer is a resource recommendation.

Comment: Theories which do not have weak coupling limit do not admit Lagrangian descriptions. Most known CFTs are strongly coupled and therefore do not have a Lagrangian.

Comment: @user1504: OP asks for res. recom., hence CW. I'm sympathetic with your POV. If OP removes all explicit ref. requests in q formulation, then the CW status can be removed.

Answer (score 6):

The natural guess is that you figure out from the CFT data what the underlying fields are, then write down the most general renormalizable Lagrangian, then figure out what special values the couplings must have to recover your CFT data.

This doesn't work.

The first and most obvious problem is that there are CFTs which don't have a Lagrangian description.  The most infamous is the 6d "(2,0) theory".

Another even bigger problem is that the CFT data doesn't uniquely determine a set of fields and couplings.   The 4d N=4 SYM theory is a self-dual CFT.  You can think of it as a gauge theory with gauge group $G$ and coupling $g$, or you can think of as a gauge theory with gauge group $^LG$ (the Langlands dual) with coupling $1/g$.  Both descriptions are Lagrangian, but how do you decide which is the "true" Lagrangian?

I think what you're asking for is essentially impossible.   Probably the best you can do is back out a Lagrangian description once given a particular classical limit.

Comment: More examples of CFTs that have two dual Lagrangian descriptions: compactified free bosons in 2d (the T-duality inverts the compactification radius), Liouville field theory (the duality inverts the coupling constant).